# Connect 4 code with min max find unique problem

Tags: java, performance, artificial-intelligence, minmax

I'm looking for a way to solve Connect 4.  I'm trying now with min max with a depth of 6.  It's not working and it keeps resulting in the same column (the first one).

I'm pretty desperate so I'll be very happy if you could find the mistakes.

```
public int findBestMove() {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myMoves = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mWidth; i++) {
            if (isColumnAvailable(i)) {
            ArrayList<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>();
            t.add(i);
            t.add(MinMax(6, mBoard, false));
            myMoves.add(t);
            
        }
        }

        int maxMoveScore = -10000;
        int bestMove = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myMoves.size(); i++) {
            int score = myMoves.get(i).get(1);
            if (score > maxMoveScore) {
                maxMoveScore = tryit;
                bestMove = myMoves.get(i).get(0);
                
            }
        
        }
        
        return bestMove;
    }

    private int MinMax(int depth,int[][] board, boolean maximizingPlayer) {
        if (depth <= 0)
            return 0;

        int winner =checkForWin() ;
        if (winner == 2)
            return depth;
        if (winner == 1)
            return -depth;
        if (isBoardFull()) {
            return 0;
        }

        int bestValue;
        
        if (maximizingPlayer)
            bestValue = -1;
        else
            bestValue = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mWidth; i++) {
            if (!isColumnAvailable(i))
                continue;
            int v = MinMax(depth - 1, board, !maximizingPlayer);
            bestValue = maximizingPlayer ? Math.max(bestValue, v) : Math.min(bestValue, v);
            
        }

        return bestValue;

    }
```

2- is the number of the AI
1- is the human player
0- is empty

Comment: Really. This question is so unclear. Who did the upvotes?

Comment: Describe your problem clearly (we shouldn't have to know any game rules), make sure all relevant code is included and learn how to indent your code.

Comment: A search depth of 6 is not nearly enough to completely solve the game of Connect 4 from the initial game state. With a search depth of 6, you will find many lines of play that still end in a non-terminal game state. You don't seem to have a heuristic function (you simply always return `0` when the maximum search depth is reached), so pretty much any move is as good as any other move (as long as the AI can still guarantee not to lose within 6 moves, which it likely can even when playing in the first column and playing more smartly after that).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.  "Not working" and "find the mistakes" are not problem specifications.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson well, I'm trying to find a way to find the "best" move for the AI, which means the AI will be able to block a win/ win  within a depth of 6 for now. Sadly It doesn't and I can't find the problem. Maybe with the recursion, as I said I'm not sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect 4 is a solved game (spoiler, player 1 wins when played perfectly).  You can read all about how the solution was accomplished in [A Knowledge-based Approach of Connect-Four](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.38.2778&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  It's quite a fascinating read because they did it at a time when computation resources were significantly harder to come by.

The general idea is to build a huge database of known value positions, then min-max with alpha-beta pruning until you reach one of the positions in the database.  Building this database was difficult due to computational and storage resources at the time this happened but you could probably achieve something similar today with less effort.

While this doesn't directly answer your question, hopefully the reference will be a good place to start your research because it includes analysis of a lot of common situations in connect 4 which you can use to help you improve your evaluation function.